# Ordering geom_bar plots of frequency by multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm creating a bar plot to display the number of survey responses from each county, and I want to group the responses by county and region. My data looks like this:

```
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  responseid region     county      industry             
       <dbl> <fct>      <fct>       <chr>                
1        137 West Coast Los Angeles Construction         
2        138 West Coast San Diego   Energy               
3        139 West Coast Orange      Professional Services
4        140 East Coast Queens      Restaurants          
5        144 West Coast San Diego   Energy               
6        145 East Coast Miami-Dade  Public Sector
```

I'm running this code:

```
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(county)), y = stat(count))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = region)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous() +
  ggtitle("Responses by County") +
  ylab("Number of Responses")+
  xlab("County") + 
  labs(fill = "Region") +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = .5, hjust = -1)
```

Which generates this plot:
[image: plot of response county by county, colored by region]

The plot is ordered by response frequency by county. I'd like to make it ordered first by region, then by response count. I want this same chart, but with all the West Coast counties in order from most to least responses, then the East Coast counties in order from most to least responses.

Faceting it doesn't give the effect I want, since it pulls the West Coast responses to a separate grid and you can't compare all the counties by the same y-axis anymore; faceting without the axis flip makes the county names overlap and become illegible.

I also tried to add an interaction argument like this but that didn't change the plot at all:

```
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(county)), y = stat(count), group = interaction(region, county))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = region)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous() +
  ggtitle("Responses by County") +
  ylab("Number of Responses")+
  xlab("County") + 
  labs(fill = "Region") +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = .5, hjust = -1)
```

Edit: This is what it looks like with facet wrap. I'm not a fan because it's harder to visually compare the bars when they don't start from the same y-axis:
[image]

If you remove the coord_flip, all the bars start from the same place, but then you can't read the county names at all.
 [image]

Comment: You should be able to achieve any arbitrary ordering of the categories on an axis by explicitly setting the order of that factor's levels: Something like `df$county <- factor(df$county, levels=c("Los Angeles", "San Diego", etc))`

Comment: Faceting, by default should share the same axes ranges across facets, unless you explicitly tell it to have free scales. Since the counties can only exist in one of the two facets, you want the counties scale to be free, so it drops the unused ones, but keep the other axis fixed, so they are comparable. Check the documentation of `facet_wrap()` for the relevant parameter options.

Comment: Explicitly setting the factors could definitely be a workaround, but I would really like a dynamic solution. I'm going to be reproducing this chart regularly as responses come in - if at some point San Diego County gets more responses than LA County, I'd have to re-set the levels to reflect that.

Comment: And the problem with faceting isn't that the axes are on different scales, I just mean that the bars are literally no longer next to each other, so they're more difficult to compare visually. That doesn't happen if I leave the coordinates unflipped, but then you can't read the county names. I'll update the post with visuals.

Comment: How about ' facet_wrap(~Region, ncol = 1'. This will plot the Regions on top of one another. I would also suggest to keep only the counties present in each region when facetting. This can be accomplished by  'facet_wrap(~Region, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y").

Comment: Thanks, that got me there! I ended up actually using facet_grid so I could add the space = "free" argument, and suppressing the title to get the effect I wanted as well.

Comment: Regarding dynamic factor releveling, I was not suggesting you hard-code the order. You can substitute there any expression that evaluates into a vector. Like a bit of code in a function that computes the order in which you want them. It is something I often do, to keep the plotting code general and reusable with other data or other requirements.

Comment: I see what you mean now, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I added the following two lines to the original plot to get the outcome I wanted. Thanks everyone who helped out!

```
facet_grid(region ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]